# add "values" in nested list

Tags: python, list

I would like to "shorten" the following list:

```py
list = [['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

to this:

```py
list = [['a', '3'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

I am trying with something like the following but I am not successful :-(

```py
output_list = []

for item in list:
    if not any((output_list[0] == item[0]) for animal in output_list):
        output_list.append([item[0], item[1]])
    else
        ...??
print(output_list)
```

Is there anybody who can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are a lot of unstated assumptions. Your basic data structure could be improved, maybe with a list of tuples of (name, count). If those are definitely supposed to be numbers, you could consider using numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
my_list = [['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

list comprehension:

```
[[letter, str(sum([int(l[-1]) for l in my_list if l[0] == letter]))] for letter in {l[0] for l in my_list} ]
```

output:

```
>>[['a', '3'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

Comment: Note that this answer unnecessarily takes *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity by iterating over the length of the list while iterating over the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list as key-value pairs, and use an intermediate dict to keep adding the value as an integer to the key, and convert the dict items back to a list of lists with a list comprehension:

```
d = {}
for k, v in lst:
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + int(v)
output_list = [[k, str(v)] for k, v in d.items()]
```

`output_list` becomes:

```
[['a', '3'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One thought using a `dict` then converting back to a `list`:

```
res = {}

for sub_list in list:
    if sub_list[0] in res:
        res[sub_list[0]] += sub_list[1]
    else:
        res[sub_list[0]] = sub_list[1]
list = [[k, v] for k,v in res.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special standard library function to do things like that, it is called `itertools.groupby`

`groupby` groups list elements by some criterion. Sum is a bit clumsy as your number are actually strings, and need to be converted to integers.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


compacted_data = []
data = sorted(data, itemgetter(0))  # sort by the first element of list
for k, g in groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):
    compacted_data.append([k, sum(map(lambda x -> int(x[2]), g))      #
```

A popular Pandas package 
offers a better, 'industrial strength' groupby, read more about pandas at

https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> list_ = [['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [[k,sum([int(el[1]) for el in v])] for k, v in groupby(list_, key=lambda x: x[0])]
[['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```